# Are there rules I should follow to create a non-traditional weapon for one of my players?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, barbarian, improvised-weaponry

One of my Barbarian players created a hat that has a bladed "tail" (like a raccoon hat, but in the shape of a dragon's tail) and I'd like to make this into an improvised martial melee weapon so they could use in close range. Are there any rules, tips, or other resources available for creating non-traditional weapons?

Comment: So this is a hat with something sharp hanging off the back that when he swings his head the 'tail' whips into his enemies?

Comment: Yes, exactly right - the "scales" of the dragon "tail" are made up from various blades, so it could be swung at an enemy in close range. I was more thinking he could swing it with a free hand, but now I'm imagining him swinging his head around and that would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 10):

### Reflavor an existing weapon

You can create any weapon you want if you use stats of an existing weapon.  Existing weapons are balanced within the game, so any other weapon using those stats would be fine.

For a "hat with a tail" I would just re-flavor a whip or flail, and say that it needs a free hand to wield.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use the [5e Weapon Balancing Framework](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y8Vc9LLa4FqUsiRuTanMavZ8yTzYVUeDESITcG1ATdk) <sup>1</sup>

Unfortunately the PHB doesn't have any examples of no-handed weapons, so some guess work is necessary here. The two-handed property is worth a negative amount of points as it prevents the user from holding other items while attacking with the weapon. A hypothetical "no-handed" property confers the opposite benefit, as the user can hold an additional item while wielding the weapon, so we can infer that this property would be worth an equal number of positive points.

Using the framework, we arrive at the following attributes.

|  | Integer Value | Feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | Martial, melee |
|  | 0 | 1d4 damage die |
|  | 8 | No-handed |
| Total | 8 |  |

This results in martial weapon with 8 points, which is exactly the average value of PHB martial weapons.

> #### Tail Blade (Martial)
>
> Damage: 1d4
> Damage Type: Slashing, probably
> Properties: No-handed

---

<sup>[1]: Disclosure: I created the tool based off of the [Detect Balance framework](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc).</sup>

Comment: Doesn't this make it essentially a dagger you can use with no hands? (Except I guess someone without Martial prof. couldn't.) There's a lot that comes with this too. By wearing the hat, are you wielding a weapon? I'm intrigued, but can't quite upvote. (Didn't downvote).

Comment: @Jason_c_o the only thing that it shares in common with a dagger is the damage die. It's a martial weapon which lacks the finesse, light, and thrown properties. So in effect it's no closer to a dagger than a whip.

Comment: It might be balanced according to the framework, but I see 0 situations where somebody would actually use this, so it feels a little underwhelming to me.

Comment: I should clarify I meant in terms of damage. Without the properties it's actual worse. Aside from the weird interactions of a "no-handed" weapon.

Comment: @EkadhSingh I could see a non-Warcaster gish utilizing this so they could keep a hand free for spell components. Regardless, there doesn't need to be a compelling reason beyond flavor for using this weapon. The trident, whip, and blowgun are statistically inferior weapons but they're in the game nonetheless.

Comment: @Andrendire +1, but I would suggest adding at least a d6 damage die *or* some kind of special feature (I was thinking something along the lines of maybe giving you a +1/2 bonus to ac next turn if you attack with this, because you had to crouch down to use it, or something similar)